# Image not picking up CSS class

Tags: html, css

I've saved down my HTML / CSS files on my desktop (all working as expected). When I upload to host (Site Ground) once of my CSS rules seems not to be working.

Class `painting4` should be strinking one of my images "images/painting8.jpg" but it doesn't appear to be working (The image appears in full size and when I view source code the class is not picked up.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```css
/************** Navigation Styles **************/

nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-right: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

nav img {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  Margin-bottom: 6px;
}

* {
  font-family: arial;
}

.logo {
  width: 40px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.last_of_nav {
  border-right: none;
  padding-right: none;
  margin-right: 70px;
}

#nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

#wrapper a:hover {
  background-color: CadetBlue;
  width: 100%;
}


/********************** Element Selectors ************************/

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

nav {
  background-color: #4682b4;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 15px 45px;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#graduation-logo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.year {
  color: CadetBlue;
}


/******** pseudo selectors *********/

nav a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

nav li a:active {
  color: white;
  background-color: CadetBlue;
}

nav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav img:hover {
  background-color: CadetBlue;
}

nav li a:hover,
a.selected {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: CadetBlue;
}


/****** Home Page ******/

.profile_picture {
  border-radius: 40%;
  float: ;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-right: 35%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  width: 30%
}

.secondary-cv-content-wrapper div {
  display: inline;
}


/****** Main body ******/

.main-content {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 0;
  float: left;
}

.main-content-home {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

.main-content-wrapper-home {
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.4);
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.intro {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 1px auto;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.main-content-wrapper h1 {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 5px;
}

.main-content-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.4);
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.main-content-wrapper h1,
.main-content-wrapper-home h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.contact {
  text-align: center;
}

.contact_list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-cv-content h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.secondary-cv-content {
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.secondary-cv-content-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border: solid 2px rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.7);
}

.secondary-cv-content-wrapper h2,
.third-content-wrapper h2,
.fourth-content-wrapper h2,
.year,
h1,
.portfolio-first-content h2,
.painting2box h2 {
  color: #4682b4;
  text-align: center;
}

.secondary-cv-content-wrapper ul {}

.third-content {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.third-content-wrapper {
  border: solid 2px rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.7);
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.third-content-wrapper a {
  display: inline;
}

.third-content-wrapper img {
  margin: 0px 0px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 140px;
  display: inline;
}

.third-content-wrapper h1 {
  margin: 0px 0px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 140px;
}

.fourth-content-wrapper {
  border: solid 2px rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.7);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fourth-content {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.secondary-cv-content-wrapper p {
  background-color: grey;
}

.portfolio-first-content {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 30px 20%;
}

.portfolio-first-content #main-painting2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px 10%;
}

.second-row-images img {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 430px;
}

#main-painting3 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.main-painting4 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}


/***** line Height ******/

p {
  line-height: 140%;
}

.painting2box {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Main footer */

.main-footer {
  border-top: solid 2px rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.7);
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.main-cv-content {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 140%;
}

.secondary-content {}


/****** Media Queries *****/

@media (max-width:950px) {
  .profile_picture {
    width: 50%;
    float: none;
    position: center
  }
  .main-content img {
    margin: 10px 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
  .profile_picture {
    width: 60%;
    float: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .main-content {
    padding: 10%
  }
  .main-content {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-first-content">

  <h1> Paintings </h1>

  <img src="images/painting 2.png" id="main-painting2">

  <div class="second-row-images">
    <img src="images/painting7.jpg">
    <img src="images/painting1.jpg">
  </div>

  <img src="images/painting6.jpg" id="main-painting3">
  <img src="images/painting8.jpg" class="main-painting4">

</div>
```

Comment: This is not a complete, functioning example. Please [edit] your question to include other relevant details, like the actual include to the stylesheet.

Comment: Works for me. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpLQaz make sure we have a [mcve] that reproduces your actual issue.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the quick response. I'm quite new to the forum so still learning the ropes, but i'll make an effort to be clearer in future. I've just added the rest of style sheet (only just figured out how i can intent selected code using CTRL K..

Comment: I edited your question to gain [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and after reviewing it, I realized that you have blank filenames (like painting 2.png) and please check it out if it works.